# Laravel 5 catching included view params in view composer

Tags: php, view, laravel-5, include

So i'am trying to make some widget service, but got one problem. In my dashboard i including number of partial views 'widget' and passing to it parameter 'settings'. Everything should be ok to me, but i want to read this 'settings' parameter in my view composer so i should be able to pass correct 'newData'
 to 'widget' view. I found something like $view->getData(); but when i use this infinite loop accurs. Any suggestions?

Note: i MUST use view composer, and CAN'T pass this 'newData' while including.

index.blade.php

```
<p>
    @include('widget', ['settings'=>'bla'])
</p>
```

Some service provider:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer(
        'widget', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\WidgetComposer'
    );
}
```

App\Http\ViewComposers\WidgetComposer.php

```
class WidgetComposer
{
    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('newData', 'someArrayWithData');
    }
}
```

widget.blade.php

```
<p>
    {!! $newData !!}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it should be **$view->getData()**;

```
class WidgetComposer
{
    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $settings = $view->getData()['settings'];
        $data = $settings == 'bla' ? 'got bla' : array(); 
        $view->with('newData', $data);
    }
}
```

This works clean project, however in my main project this causes infinity loop in renderer. Not sure if this is because of some variables that i shouldnt be using here or because of some dependicies. I will add comment if found out something.